# Округление числа

Tags: jquery, округление

Здраствуйте.
Есть возможность с помощю jquery округлить допустим 7.6545454 до 8?
спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery и округление чисел???? )))

Код (округлит число A, оставив 3 знака после запятой)

```
    Math.round(А).toFixed(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Math.round()](http://javascript.ru/Math.round)